# Having issue with typescript dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I am building an typescirpt dictionary like that:

```
const skills = x
        .map(y => y.skills)
        .flat(1)
        .map(z => {
          return { [z.id]: { skill: z } };
        });
```

That is the array I am getting by the code above:

```
{ 7ff2c668-0e86-418a-a962-4958262ee337: {skill: {…}} }
{ c6846331-2e11-45d6-ab8d-306c956332fc: {skill: {…}} }
{ 0fc0cb61-f44d-4fd0-afd1-18506380b55e: {skill: {…}} }
{ 36dc0b74-84ee-4be2-a91c-0a91b4576a21: {skill: {…}} }
```

Now the issue is I can not access the dictionary by key:

```
const id = '7ff2c668-0e86-418a-a962-4958262ee337';
const one = myArr.find(x => x === id); // returns undefined
const two = myArr[id]; // returns undefined
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: What is `myArr`?

Comment: @NickParsons that is the array of elements like `{ 7ff2c668-0e86-418a-a962-4958262ee337: {skill: {…}} }`

Comment: and is `x` an `id` like `7ff2c668-0e86-418a-a962-4958262ee337` ?

Comment: @NickParsons correct

Comment: make use of Map as suggested , that gives you almost same functionality as dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get the key of each of your objects. In your case the key of each of your objects is its id. Then use that to check whether it equals `x` (you search id).

See example below:

```js
const myArr = [
{"7ff2c668-0e86-418a-a962-4958262ee337": {skill: 1}},
{"c6846331-2e11-45d6-ab8d-306c956332fc": {skill: 2}},
{"0fc0cb61-f44d-4fd0-afd1-18506380b55e": {skill: 3}},
{"36dc0b74-84ee-4be2-a91c-0a91b4576a21": {skill: 4}}],

id = "36dc0b74-84ee-4be2-a91c-0a91b4576a21",
one = myArr.findIndex(x => Object.keys(x)[0] === id); // the index of the object which has the search id as its key.

myArr[one] = {newKey: "newValue"}; // set the index found to have a new object
console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: How I would reassign the element in the array by `x (id)` ? Any ideas how to make the square brackets working?

Comment: So you want to swap the object at the with the key of `id` with a new object?

Comment: Yes, that is basically the whole point of what I was trying to achieve in the end. Thought I can do that using square brackets.

Comment: @sreginogemoh the square brackets are only used to retrieve things (unless you set them equal to something else). I've updated my answer. Does this do what you want it to? Here it will update the `skill` based on the `id` you give it

Comment: I need to swap the object by id in `myArray`

Comment: @sreginogemoh ok, I've changed it again to use `findIndex` now it will change the entire object at the index for where the `id` matches the key. Is this what you were after?

Comment: `the square brackets are only used to retrieve things (unless you set them equal to something else)` - can you give a bit more input on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188456/discussion-between-nick-parsons-and-sreginogemoh).

Answer (score 1):

You are now creating an array of objects. I suggest you create an object instead, with your ids as keys

Example:

```
const skills = x
    .map(y => y.skills)
    .flat(1)
    .reduce((acc, z) => {
        acc[z.id] = z;
        return acc;
    }, {});
```

Your `myArr` is going to look something like:

```
{
    '7ff2c668-0e86-418a-a962-4958262ee337': {...}
    'c6846331-2e11-45d6-ab8d-306c956332fc': {...},
    '0fc0cb61-f44d-4fd0-afd1-18506380b55e': {...},
    '36dc0b74-84ee-4be2-a91c-0a91b4576a21': {...}
}
```

You can then access it the way you intended:

```
const skill = myArr['7ff2c668-0e86-418a-a962-4958262ee337'];
```

Comment: I thought I was building a typescript dictionary `[id: string]: any`

Answer (score 1):

make use of map  that can help,

`Map` is a new data structure introduced in ES6. It allows you store key-value pairs similar to other programming languages e.g. Java, C#.

```
let map = new Map();
const skills = x
        .map(y => y.skills)
        .flat(1)
        .map(z => {
          map.set(z.Id,  { skill: z })
          return  map;
        });

//Get entries
amp.get("7ff2c668-0e86-418a-a962-4958262ee337");     //40

//Check entry is present or not
map.has("7ff2c668-0e86-418a-a962-4958262ee337");       //true
```